# How to best do foreach together with count in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have been trying to do some work in excel, but i seem to be stuck on one point

in colum "A" i have: a, b, c, d, e
in colum "B" i have: done, started, completed
in colum "C" to colum "S" i have: some "X"'s but not in all fields.

So my question is how do i do the following

```
foreach row in excel.A
   Where Bx is done
   count("X", $row)
```

I have tried pivot, countif, sumproduct but i cant seem to get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: If I understand you; you want a count of X's where completion=done. In that case COUNTIF should work just fine for you. Can you provide us with the COUNTIF formula you used?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. I've formatted it for you, but it's still not clear. Can you please take a screen shot of your Excel sheet and instead of attempting some code (which doesn't even state if it's psuedo or another scripting language like Ruby/Python) also explain, in English what you want

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want to use `SUMPRODUCT`. Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B5="Done")*(C1:S5="X"))
```

This will return the number of times `X` appears in columns C through S for all rows where the value in column B is `Done`.

The multiplication makes Excel treat the Boolean arrays as numeric arrays. This keeps `SUMPRODUCT` from returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
=IF(B1="done",COUNTIF(C1:S1,"X"),"")
```

This is, of course, case sensitive. This counts each row and gives a number, unless it's not "done" then it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that any cell in columns C to S that don't have an X in them have nothing in them. If that's the case then you could simplify a little by just using a COUNTA:

```
=IF(B2="done",COUNTA(C2:S2),"")
```

Keep in mind that if those X's are entered via a formula (as in the blank cells have formula in them) then this won't work as the cells will count as having something in them.